# How to render QGraphicsScene animations out to a movie file?

Tags: c++, python, qt, render, movie

Does anybody know how to render an animation from QGraphicsView / QGraphicsScene out to a movie file format (AVI, MPG, MP4, MOV, something) on disk? I've seen examples for rendering the scene out to an image file with QPrinter. Any ideas on if rendering animations to movies is possible?

I suppose worst case would be to step frame-by-frame and save images, then combine the images into a movie with some external tool... Any better suggestions? Is it possible to do this from QT directly somehow?

Thanks!
- Brian

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the ways is to use `QPixmap` for capturing the images,

```
QPixmap pixMap = QPixmap::grabWidget(view);
```

Use `QPixmap::toImage()` to convert it to `QImage`.

And using [QtFFmpegWrapper](http://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/) for creating the video directly from `QImage`.

You do not need to use an external tool. Just an external library.